# android.intent.action.SEND; doing it wrong?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

So I'm updating an app I created a while ago. In the AndroidManifest.xml I have the following (along with an `<intent-filter>` for `android.intent.action.MAIN`) inside an `<activity>`:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/send_label" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

If I remember correctly, when I first created this app, the above (minus the `android:label` and `android:icon` bits) worked; my app would show up in the "Share" menu. A couple weeks ago I noticed a review of my app on the Market saying that it didn't show up when trying to Share stuff. I checked, and sure enough, it wasn't there.

Is the fact that I have two `<intent-filter>` blocks for one Activity confusing it? Did I break something between then and now, did something change in the Android API, or what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need to specify a category?
(such as `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

Comment: Wow, yeah. Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.